# Can't extend into or format unallocated space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have installed a new HDD, Disk 2 below. From the start it showed up as two unallocated spaces. The only not greyed out choice was to format the first allocated space so i did. Now i want to extend the formatted one to also include the unallocated space but the option is greyed out. I cant format the unallocated space. What to do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your disk has the legacy MS-DOS/MBR partition table, which can only allocate up to `2TiB`.

To use the rest of your disk, you'll need to convert or reformat with the new GUID Partition Table (GPT).

[Microsoft has provided two ways to reformat your disk with GPT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725671(v=ws.11).aspx), but you will lose all your data in the process.

There are some [third-party solutions](https://wayback.archive.org/web/20160514000617/http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk) that may be able to convert from MBR to GPT in place.

---

Here are my preferred ways to convert a MBR disk to a GPT disk because all you have to do is run one command:

### Windows: [`gptgen`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptgen/)

If you have a different disk, replace `2` below with the number of your MBR disk shown in Disk Management or in `list disk` in `diskpart.exe`:

```
gptgen.exe \\.\\physicaldrive2
```

### Linux: [`sgdisk`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sgdisk)

Find your MBR disk using `lsblk -p` if necessary and then run:

```
sgdisk -g /dev/sdb
```

… where `/dev/sdb` is your MBR disk.

Comment: I did it the Microsoft way ("To change a master boot record disk into a GUID partition table disk using the Windows interface") since i had no data on the disk. Thanks